# When using the Frobenius method, and r1-r2 is neither zero nor a positive integer, can you use the Wronskian to find the second solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method, wronskian

When using the Frobenius method, and r1-r2 is neither zero nor a positive integer, can you use the Wronskian to find the second solution? Basically, do I have to repeat the substitution with the second root in order to find the second solution to an ODE or is there an easier way with the Wronskian?